# How do I create a button that sends an HTTP GET request to a secure URL when clicked?

Tags: python, jquery, html, django, ajax

I am building a web app where a user searches for a camera (located on a remote network with a dyndns domain) and is shown a button to trigger a siren on the camera. When the user clicks the button, they should not see the page refresh or anything happen (other than the button maybe being disabled). The button is sending an HTTP GET request to the website:

`example.com:port/file.xml?relay2State=2`.

However, I'm unsure how to handle when the user refreshes or hits the back button, and how the browser stores the request in its history. I don't want the user to be able to press the back button and activate this request again, or refresh the page and activate it. Neither should the user be able to save the button request as a bookmark. Essentially, this event should only be able to fire off when the button is clicked, and the button should be disabled for 30 seconds across the whole website (all users should see the button being disabled).

This led to the question: should this be a GET or POST request, and how do I incorporate it via button?

Here is the relevant code:

```
<!-- siren_search.html -->

{% if cameras %}

<button id="trigger-all-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Trigger all sirens</button>

<table id="camera-table" class="table table-hover">

    <thead>
        <tr class="header">
            <th scope="col" style="width:33%;">Asset Name</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width:33%;">Job Site</th>
            <th scope="col" style="width:33%;"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        {% for camera in cameras %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ camera.asset_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ camera.site.name }}</td>
            <td><button id="{{ camera.asset_name }}-btn" type="button" class="btn siren-btn btn-outline-danger">Siren</button></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

</table>

{% endif %}
```

```
# views.py

def siren_search(request):

    context = {}

    if request.method == 'GET':

        term = request.GET.get('query')
        if term:
            try:
                jobsite = JobSite.objects.get(name__iexact = term)
                cameras = jobsite.camerasystem_set.all()
                context = {
                    'cameras': cameras,
                    'numberOfCameras': len(cameras)
                }

            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                pass

    ## Add functionality to handle button click and make the following request
    pulseSiren = requests.get(f'{camera.name}.example.com:port/file.xml?relay2State=2', auth=('user', 'pass'))

    return render(request, 'siren_search.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you ask is not a simple solution and you actually have two questions:

1) How do you trigger a URL without changing the browser?

Answer: do it asynchronously. This requires Javascript and you may find a library like JQuery to ease the creation of this solution. For example consider JQuery's [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) Using GET or POST is immaterial to the solution

2) How do you communicate with any other browsers and disable their buttons if one button is clicked?

Answer: This is not simple. The Browser to Server communication is pulled by the browser, not pushed by the server. One option is to use asynchronous Javascript to poll the server so the server and provide an update about the status of the buttons. But then you have to handle the case of a button being clicked on a browser after it's been clicked on another browser, but before the second clicking browser got the updated button state information in it's latest poll.

Hopefully this answer provides some information that's helpful.

Comment: For 2), WebSockets seem like the modern solution.

Comment: If I don't want the user to be able to re-trigger the event upon pressing the back button or pressing the refresh button, how would I handle that?

Comment: Also, if the button click routes to the url on my server `/buttonClick/siren`, how do I prevent the user from just typing that url into their browser and still triggering the button event?